# Making sure a file path is complete in grep

Tags: regex, unix, command-line, grep

I had to change the path of my template directory and I want to make sure all my files refer to "templates/app/xxx.html" instead of "templates/xxx.html"

How can I use grep to see all lines of "*.html", but not "app/*.html"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there's only one per line, you could start with something like:

```
grep '\.html' | grep -v '/app/.*\.html'
```

The first will deliver all those that have `.html`. The second will strip from that list all those that have the `app` variant, leaving only those that violate your check.

Obviously, this may need to be adjusted depending on how tricky your lines are (more than one per line, other stuff on the line and so forth) but this "give me a list of all possible violations then remove those that aren't violations" is a tried and tested method.

For example (as Kent suggests), you may want to ensure that the HTML files are all *directly* in the `app` directories instead of possibly `app/something/xyzzy.html`. In that case, you could simply adjust your second filter to ensure this:

```
grep '\.html' | grep -v '/app/[^/]*\.html'
```

Using `[^/]*` (any number of non-`/` characters) instead of `.*` (any number of characters, including `/`) will leave in those that don't have the HTML file directly in the `app` directory.

Comment: if a link like `...foo/bar/app/blah/x.html` your grep will fail

Comment: @Kent, I don't think you're right on that. My first `grep` passes that through and the second strips it out, as required. But even if it _didn't_ work properly, that's where the "depending on how tricky your lines are" part of my answer would kick in.

Comment: I didn't say your answer is completely wrong. and your "depending on how tricky your lines are" does make sense. I was just saying, your grep line cannot match `...foo/bar/app/blah/x.html`. what output do you get from ` echo "...foo/bar/app/blah/x.html"| grep '\.html' | grep -v '/app/.*\.html'
`?

Comment: @Kent: I get nothing from that. As stated, it passes the first filter (because it has `.html`) and is rejected by the second (since it has `/app/XXX.html` where `XXX` is anything).

Comment: yes, i thought `...foo/bar/app/blah/x.html` should show in result. in another word, we need that line. only path "..../app/*.html" should be filtered out, but "..../app/../../../*.html" not.

Comment: @Kent, never mind, I think I see your contention now. You are assuming (perhaps rightly) that the `app` must immediately precede the html bit with no intervening directories. I assumed otherwise, but I'll put that in as an example of one of the possible adjustments.

Comment: right, that's why I used look-behind. however your line may meet OP's need already.

Answer (score 0):

It might also be useful to know which files contained unwanted references to the old path.

I'd do something like this (disclaimer: not tested! But I copied some of it from paxdiablo, so that part's probably right.)

```
find /path/to/files_to_check -type f -name "*.html" -exec grep '\.html' {} \; /dev/null | grep -v '/app/.*\.html'
```

The `find` command searches a directory hierarchy for regular files with names ending in `.html`.  Adjust as necessary for your situation.

For each of these files, `grep` is run with two file arguments: `{}` representing the target path, and `/dev/null` to get `grep` to prefix the matching line with the filename it occurred in.  From that, we strip out anything matching `'/app/.*\.html'`.  What's left is a list of lines that need to be fixed, along with the filenames where they were found.

Comment: same as paxdiablo's solution, doesn't work for path `...foo/bar/app/blah/x.htm`

Answer (score 0):

or
use this `grep -P '(?<!/app)/[^/]*\.html`

**test:**

```
kent$  echo ".../app/a/b/x.html
.../foo/myapp/y.html
.../foo/app/z.html"|grep -P '(?<!/app)/[^/]*\.html'

.../app/a/b/x.html
.../foo/myapp/y.html
```

note that this will ignore `..../app/*.html`, but `.../myapp/*.html` or `.../app/foo/x.html` will be matched.